# Argument of type 'User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EntityTarget<BaseEntity>'

Tags: typescript, entity, typeorm

I'm sending an **"Entity"** to the function and using it inside the function. But it is giving me this error.

```
export type Entities = User | Blog | Service
```

```
import AppDataSource from '../database'
import { Entities } from '../entity/index'
import User from '../entity/User'

const getList = async (entity: Entities) => {
  const list = (await AppDataSource.manager.find(entity))
}
```

> Argument of type 'Entities' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EntityTarget'.
> Type 'User' is not assignable to type 'EntityTarget'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnUrM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to extend from EntityTarget:

```js
export interface User extends EntityTarget<unknown> {}
export interface Blog extends EntityTarget<unknown> {}
export interface Service extends EntityTarget<unknown> {}

export type Entities = User | Blog | Service

import AppDataSource from '../database'
import { Entities } from '../entity/index'
import User from '../entity/User'

const getList = async (entity: Entities) => {
  const list = (await AppDataSource.manager.find(entity))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got such an error in the code above "'X' type argument cannot be assigned to 'X' type parameter" I did it this way to solve the problem:

```
import { EntityTarget } from 'typeorm'
import AppDataSource from '../database'

export type _User = EntityTarget<'User'>
export type _Blog = EntityTarget<'Blog'>
export type _Service = EntityTarget<'Service'>

export type Entities = _User | _Blog | _Service

export const getList = async (entity: Entities) => {
  const list = (await AppDataSource.manager.find(entity))
}
```

But I'm not sure if it's healthy

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem this way, it seems more logical. **Thanks**

```
import { EntityTarget } from 'typeorm'
import AppDataSource from '../database'

const getList = async <E>(entity: EntityTarget<E>) => {
  const list = await AppDataSource.manager.find(entity)
}
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining the changes you made from the example in your question which helped to solve your issue. Code-only answers are generally considered low-quality on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to stackoverflow. I'm learning